# Autocalculation normals for buffer geometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

In order to reduce transferred data I want to calculate vertex normals late after buffer geometry information is already obtained. I know how to do this for simple geometry like this:

```
object.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
object.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

How to apply this approach for buffer geometry?

Comment: Can you please add some code that you have already tried?

Comment: Fixed typos and misspellings.

Comment: `THREE.BufferGeometry()` has the method `.computeVertexNormals()` [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L657)